# export many files from a table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a sql query that generate a table with the below format

```
|sex  |country|popularity|
|null |null   | x        | 
|null |value  | x        |
|value|null   | x        |
|value|null   | x        |
|null |value  | x        |
|value|value  | x        |
```

value for sex column could be woman,man
value for country could be Italy,England,US etc.

x is a int

Now i would like to save four files based on data combination(value,null). So file1 consist of (value,value) for column sex,country.
file2 consist of (value,null) for column sex,country. file3 consist of (null,value) and file4 consist of
(null,null).

I have searched a lot of things but i couldn't find any useful info. I have also tried the below

```
val df1 = data.withColumn("combination",concat(col("sex") ,lit(","), col("country")))
df1.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("combination").format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save("text.csv")
```

but i receive more files because this command generate files based on all possible data of (sex-country).
Same with the below

```
val df1 = data.withColumn("combination",concat(col("sex")))
    df1.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("combination").format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save("text.csv")
```

Is there any command similar to partitionby that gives me a combination of pairs (value,null) and not for columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the columns into Boolean depending on whether they are null or not, and concat into a string, which will look like "true_true", "true_false" etc.

```
df = df.withColumn("coltype", concat(col("sex").isNull(), lit("_"), col("country").isNull()))
df.coalesce(1)
  .write
  .partitionBy("coltype")
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save("output")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. It helps a lot. :D